# Como converter em Java um arquivo PDF para TXT?

Tags: java

Existe alguma forma em java para converter um arquivo de extensão PDF para a extensão TXT?

Comment: O conteudo do PDF pode variar muito, não tem como extrair exatamente algo padronizado, existem muitos documentos PDF que foram gerados de arquivos .doc Deve haver sim, mas não será nada fácil. Isto é apenas uma dica do que você tera pela frente, vou pesquisar e ver se existe alguma lib. Até mais.

Comment: Ja tenho ciencia desse empecilho, mas ajudaria mostrando e exemplificando uma forma e ficaria grato @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode tentar utilizar a biblioteca [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), que possui algumas funcionalidades prontas para a extração de texto de arquivos PDF. Uma forma de fazer isso seria:

```
public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        out.println(strategy.getResultantText());
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Onde o parâmetro `pdf` é o arquivo PDF que deve ser extraído o texto e o parâmetro `txt` é o arquivo TXT de destino.

Este trecho de código foi retirado de um exemplo pronto, criado pelo desenvolvedor do iText. Este exemplo, bem como o TXT resultante, podem ser encontrados neste [link](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=277).

Comment: A biblioteca PDFBox também poderá ajudá-lo